# Init infinite loop on bootup (shell/Openwrt)

Tags: shell, infinite-loop, openwrt

I've been trying to generate and infinite loop in OpenWRT, and I've succeeded:

```
#!/bin/sh /etc/rc.common
while [ true ] 
do  
    # Code to run
    sleep 15
done
```

This code works as a charm if I execute it as ./script. However, I want this to start on its own when I turn on my router. I've placed the script in `/etc/init.d`and enabled it with `chmod +x script`.

Regardless, the program doesn't start running at all. My guess is that I shouldn't execute this script on boot up but have a script that calls this other script. I haven't been able to work this out.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I have messed with init scripts of OpenWRT in my previous projects. I would like contribute to Rich Alloway's answer (for the ones who will likely to drop here from google search). His answer only covers for "traditional SysV style init scripts" as it is mentioned in the page that he gave link [Init Scripts](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/techref/initscripts).

There is new process management daemon, Procd that you might find in your OpenWRT version. Sadly documentation of it has not been completed yet; [Procd Init Scripts](https://wiki.openwrt.org/inbox/procd-init-scripts).

There are minor differences like they have pointed out in their documentation :

> - procd expects services to run in the foreground,
> - Different shebang,
> - line: #!/bin/sh /etc/rc.common Explicitly use procd USE_PROCD=1
> - start_service() instead of start()

A simple init script for procd would look like :

```
#!/bin/sh /etc/rc.common

# it is run order of your script, make it high to not mess up with other init scripts
START=100 

USE_PROCD=1

start_service() {
  procd_open_instance
  procd_set_param command /target/to/your/useless/command -some -useless -shit -here 
}
```

I have posted some [blog post](http://blog.kerematam.com/2016/12/creating-script-to-run-on-boot-for.html) about it while ago that might help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a file in `/etc/rc.d/` with an `Sxx` prefix in order for the system to execute the script at boot time.  This is usually accomplished by having the script in `/etc/init.d` and a symlink in `/etc/rc.d` pointing to the script.

The `S` indicates that the script should run at startup while the `xx` dictates the order that the script will run.  Scripts are executed in naturally increasing order:  `S10boot` runs before `S40network` and `S50cron` runs before `S50dropbear`.

Keep in mind that the system may not continue to boot with the script that you have shown here!

`/etc/init.d/rcS` calls each script sequentially and waits for the current one to exit before calling the next script.  Since your script is an infinite loop, it will never exit and `rcS` may not complete the boot process.

Including `/etc/rc.common` will be more useful if you use functions in your script like `start()`, `stop()`, `restart()`, etc and add `START` and `STOP` variables which describe when the script should be executed during boot/shutdown.

Your script can then be used to enable and disable itself at boot time by creating or removing the symlink:  `/etc/init.d/myscript enable`

See also [OpenWRT Boot Process](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/techref/process.boot#etcrcdrcs_script_at_startup) and [Init Scripts](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/techref/initscripts)

-Rich Alloway (RogueWave)